# Database app crashes on adding onClick listener to the buttons

Tags: android, xml, database, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I have been trying to set up a simple database like I've done before. But this single page app crashes as soon as I add onClick listener to the 2 buttons I have. It's a very simple app to add player name and score to the database, and then find by name the scores. Earlier I had my layout in fragment_main.xml, but I changed it to activity_main.xml. Here's the code for my MainActivity, Database adapter, Layout-xml and LogCat.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button add, find;
    EditText name, score;
    private DBAdapter dbHelper;
    private boolean isUpdate = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        dbHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
        name =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        score = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    }

    public void newPlayer(View view){
        dbHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
        String pName = name.getText().toString();
        int pScore = Integer.parseInt(score.getText().toString());
        Player player = new Player(pName, pScore);
        dbHelper.addPlayer(player);
        name.setText("D");
        score.setText("1");
    }

    public void findPlayer(){
        dbHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
        Player player = dbHelper.getPlayerByName(name.getText().toString());
        if (player != null){
            score.setText(player.getScore());
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't find in database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

AND the **DBAdapter Handler** is:

```
    package com.example.anotherdatabase;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "ItemDB.db";
    Context context;
    private static final String TABLE_ITEM = "Players"; 
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_SCORE = "score";
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCORE};

    public DBAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_ITEM +"( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                "name TEXT, "+
                "score INTEGER )";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEM_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_ITEM);
        // create fresh Items table
        this.onCreate(db);

    }

public void addPlayer(Player player){

//      get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, player.getName()); 
        values.put(KEY_SCORE, player.getScore());

        // insert
        long insert = db.insert(TABLE_ITEM, null, values); 
        if(insert == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to save to the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // close
        db.close(); 
    }

public Player getPlayerById(int id){

    // 1. get reference to readable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // 2. build query
    Cursor cursor = 
            db.query(TABLE_ITEM,
            COLUMNS,
            " id = ?",  
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);

    // 3. if we got results get the first one
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    // 4. build Item object
    Player player = new Player();

    player.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    player.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    player.setScore(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
    db.close();
    return player;
    }

public Player getPlayerByName(String name){

    // 1. get reference to readable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // 2. build query
    Cursor cursor = 
            db.query(TABLE_ITEM,
            COLUMNS,
            " name = ?",  
            new String[]{name}, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);

    // 3. if we got results get the first one
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    // 4. build Item object
    Player player = new Player();
    player.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    player.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    player.setScore(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
    db.close();
    return player;
    }

public Player updatePlayer(Player player) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, player.getName()); 
    values.put(KEY_SCORE, player.getScore());
    // insert
    int i = db.update(TABLE_ITEM, values, KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(player.getId())} );
    Log.d("number of rows updated:", i+"");
    // close
    db.close();
    return null;

    }

public int deletePlayerById(String playerId) {

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // 2. delete
    int result = db.delete(TABLE_ITEM,
            KEY_ID+" = ?",
            new String[] { playerId });
    // 3. close
    db.close();  
    return result;

    }


}
```

And **activity_main.xml** is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.anotherdatabase.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Add"
        android:onClick="newPlayer" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Find"
        android:onClick="findPlayer" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Log-cat : **

```
07-10 11:29:59.423: D/AndroidRuntime(26313): Shutting down VM
07-10 11:29:59.423: W/dalvikvm(26313): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4174bba8)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313): Process: com.example.anotherdatabase, PID: 26313
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    ... 11 more
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    at com.example.anotherdatabase.MainActivity.newPlayer(MainActivity.java:46)
07-10 11:29:59.423: E/AndroidRuntime(26313):    ... 14 more
07-10 11:30:50.658: I/Adreno-EGL(27015): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
07-10 11:30:50.688: D/OpenGLRenderer(27015): Enabling debug mode 0
07-10 11:31:00.238: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27015): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-10 11:33:41.480: D/AndroidRuntime(28077): Shutting down VM
07-10 11:33:41.480: W/dalvikvm(28077): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4174bba8)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077): Process: com.example.anotherdatabase, PID: 28077
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.anotherdatabase/com.example.anotherdatabase.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at com.example.anotherdatabase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
07-10 11:33:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28077):    ... 11 more
07-10 11:33:43.442: I/Process(28077): Sending signal. PID: 28077 SIG: 9
07-10 11:36:58.490: I/Adreno-EGL(29284): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
07-10 11:36:58.531: D/OpenGLRenderer(29284): Enabling debug mode 0
07-10 11:37:03.906: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29284): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-10 11:38:13.851: I/Adreno-EGL(29892): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
07-10 11:38:13.881: D/OpenGLRenderer(29892): Enabling debug mode 0
07-10 11:38:29.908: D/AndroidRuntime(29892): Shutting down VM
07-10 11:38:29.908: W/dalvikvm(29892): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4174bba8)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892): Process: com.example.anotherdatabase, PID: 29892
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    ... 11 more
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    at com.example.anotherdatabase.MainActivity.newPlayer(MainActivity.java:47)
07-10 11:38:29.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29892):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: NullPointerException at line 46 of MainActivity. Which line is line 46?

Comment: public void newPlayer(View view){ or String pName = name.getText().toString();

Comment: int pScore = Integer.parseInt(score.getText().toString().trim());

Comment: Maybe your EditText 'name' was not found when inflating the view? Try cleaning the project.

Comment: Cleaned the project, but the error still persists

Answer (score 1):

Your following line has a problem. score is an edittext and it is empty hence it is giving you problem in following line. make sure score that some int value.

```
 int pScore = Integer.parseInt(score.getText().toString());
```

Also, to remove other error you need to clean your project and then re-build it.

Comment: But how's score field empty, when I'm giving a number in input?

Comment: You are first accessing the score field and later you are giving number input. Try giving number input first and then access it.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I do that?